# Ubuntu Live USB is not working as expected

Tags: live-usb

I have tried with both Linux live usb creator and universal usb creator. The result is the same. I used the ubuntu 12.04 image when was asked to provide the iso.

And when I booted via the USB it presents the installation option.

But what I wanted was a live USB ie that will boot from the USB and it will have an in memory OS with shell where I can execute commands. Besides it will have an option to install to hard disk if wanted.

This is the way I have a CentOS live usb working. But I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing Ubuntu either from CD/DVD or USB, and changing the system's BIOS to boot from the desired device, once the system boots this is the first screen that you will get:

[image]

The option labeled 1 will allow to boot Ubuntu fully, and the ability to use it, without any changes made to you system.  After you click on the button labeled Try Ubuntu, it will boot up, and give you the desktop, from there you can use it fully, and it will give you the option to install as shown in the image below:

[image]

Now if you click on the button labeled 2 Install Ubuntu, that will start the hard drive installation.

Ubuntu Server does not have a live CD.  The other option that's close to that is installing it inside a virtual machine.

This allows you to test, and play with the server as desired, but it doesn't change anything in your system.   And for that you can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  VirtualBox is free
and you can install it either under Ubuntu desktop or Windows.

Comment: That is it! That is what I am trying to say. I don't have the same interface. According to the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD the boot menu should contain a 'try' option as depicted. But in my case there is no such menu. it has install option but no try option. FYI, I am using ubuntu server not the ubuntu desktop.

Comment: I just updated my answer to add info about Ubuntu Server.